# Highlight Entire Line in RichTextBox C#

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I have a richtextbox in my C# winforms application and cannot figure out a way to highlight the entire line (the text part + any empty spaces).  I am only able to highlight the text on the line using the following code:

```
firstCharIndex = richTextBox.Text.IndexOf(header);
headerLine = richTextBox.GetLineFromCharIndex(firstCharIndex);
headerLineText = richTextBox.Lines[headerLine];

int lastCharIndex = richTextBox.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(headerLine + 1);

//richTextBox.Select(firstCharIndex, headerLineText.Length);
richTextBox.Select(firstCharIndex, lastCharIndex - firstCharIndex);

if (richTextBox.SelectionBackColor != System.Drawing.Color.DarkGray)
{
    richTextBox.SelectionBackColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkGray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the second overload of "select" for less calculations.

Look into comments.

```
        //Rich text box
        richTextBox1.Text = "test test1 test test                              ";

        //Get the first index in the line from where you want to select.
        int firstCharIndex = richTextBox1.Text.IndexOf("test1");

        //Get the line based on character index.
        int line = richTextBox1.GetLineFromCharIndex(firstCharIndex);

        //Get the line it self.
        string headerLineText = richTextBox1.Lines[line];

        //Use second ovrload of select method and pass length of the line as second parameter
        //with the below approach, you can start highlighting from any where in the line.
        richTextBox1.Select(firstCharIndex, headerLineText.Length- firstCharIndex);
```

Comment: I already tried that.   It only highlights the part of the line which contains the text.  Also, my form (and hence textbox) is resizable.  So if I increase the width, the line should still remain highlighted.

Comment: If you do not have a valid next line, with your code, for lastCharIndex  value will be -1. So I do not suggest to use that. Try exactly as I said in my code

Comment: I noticed you right padded the text with empty space.  This is what I did before but the problem is you don't know how wide the form will be.  Is there no way to highlight the entire line without manually adding empty space at the end of the text?

Comment: You mean the space after text??. That space is not part of the text.... So you wont have any metrics for it.

Comment: I copied your code into my program and it only highlighted the string contained in the .Text property.  But I want to highlight the entire line/row in the textbox so even if I increase the width of the form (textbox), the entire row is still highlighted.  I hope I'm clear.